# Numpy ndArray is not flattening with flatten()

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy

I have a numpy ndArray which is of shape (500,20,8) of float64. Keep in mind however that when I get the shape of such array, I get the following output. I do not know if this is OK:

```
mat = sp.loadmat('RIS_auth.mat')

mat_data = mat['X'][0] #get ndarray of data

print(mat_data.shape, mat_data[0].shape)

Output:
(500,) (20, 8)
```

With this, I am new to numpy so forgive me for my ignorance, but when I try to flatten the array, absolutely nothing changes, not even the shape:

```
mat_data = mat['X'][0] #get ndarray of data

mat_data_flat = mat_data.flatten()

print(mat_data_flat.shape, mat_data_flat[0].shape)

Output:
(500,) (20, 8)
```

And the data and array when printed out looks exactly the same. Am I missing something?

For reference, all of my arrays and nested arrays are numpy, and they look similar to:

```
[array([[1.87048798e-05, 5.36669926e-05, ..., ...]])
 ...
 array([[7.48048596e-05, 3.07272543e-06, ..., ...]])]
```

Edit:
I find that running:

```
mat_data_flat = np.concatenate(mat_data).ravel()
```

Does fully flatten it, but not flatten()?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it looks like the array is already flat and contains nested arrays. That's a bit odd, but if the data is saved that way, it'd make sense. You should probably make a [mre].

Comment: Right.  It looks like what you have is a Python list of numpy arrays.  Is that correct?

Comment: `mat_data` is a 1d array `(500,)`, object dtype.  It is already 'flat'.  `flatten` does not work across that 'object' layer.  If the component arrays match in shape, `concatenate` can join them into one array. Check the resulting shape, you probably don't need the `ravel`.

Comment: `loadmat` often makes an object dtype array like this, replicating a MATLAB cell.  Since the inner arrays are (20,8), I expect `concatenate` makes a (500*20, 8) array, so you do need the ravel to get (500*20*8).  Depending on the matlab source your `loadmat` arrays can have a complex numpy structure.  Only a basic `matrix` will translate into a simple numpy numeric array.

Comment: `mat['X'][0]` suggests that `mat['x']` is (1,500)`.  Everything in matlab is at least 2d.

Comment: @hpaulj You are completely correct, what would this entail?

Comment: Concatenate on the (500,) shape is the right approach.